# Can not create file in specific directory inside the project (war file) Java deployed on wildfly on ubuntu(The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a directory and a file inside it in Java (spring) and it is working fine when I execute it on Windows, but after deploying the war file on Wildfly on linux it's throwing the error:

**code snippet:**

```
String filePath = "reports/"; 
File f = new File(filePath);
if (!f.exists()) {
    boolean b = f.mkdir();
    if(b) {
        File xlFile = new File(filePath+ File.separator + "report.xlsx");
    }
}
```

Error after deploying it on wildfly that is running on Ubuntu:

```
{
    "data": "java.io.FileNotFoundException: reports/Attendance.xlsx (No such file or directory)",
    "message": "Error while writing file",
    "status": 400,
    "isSuccess": true
}
```

Please guide.

I tried many ways to do this but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution: in Linux keep in mind the difference between forward slash ' / ' and backward slash ' \ ' and instead of creating a folder inside the war file use any Linux directory like (/tmp or /opt), so the code will remain same as I mentioned above, the only thing I changed is the directory path and it works fine:

```
String filePath = "/tmp/reports/"; 
File f = new File(filePath);
if (!f.exists()) {
boolean b=f.mkdir();
if(b) {
File xlFile = new File(filePath+ File.separator + "report.xlsx");
}
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to worry about separators. A forward slash should always work. Plus, it's better to use `java.nio` to manipulate paths: `String filePath = "/tmp/reports/";Path reportRoot = Path.of(filePath);Files.createDirectories(reportRoot);Path xlFile = reportRoot.resolve("report.xlsx");`

Comment: For maximum portability, you could (probably should) do `Path reportRoot = Path.of(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "reports");`